# How to make run "yarn" in folder A install the node modules in folder B by nesting folder B in folder A's node modules without Babel access

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, watch, craco

I am having a folder which has two React folder inside at the same level.  I nested File B in File A node_modules, and put "dependencies": {"B":"./B"}" in File A pacakage.json. The reason I am doing this is because File A uses the redux in File B, hence every time I run yarn in File A should also install the node modules in File B. This is normally done by babel config, however my boss uses "create react app" which do not allow me to directly amend the babel config. Instead I am required to use Craco to add watch in File B, so that File A knows its library update. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a `preinstall` on your `package.json` of your root folder (folder `A`), so to install the dependencies of all your nested projects in one:

```json
"scripts": {
   "preinstall": "cd ./B; npm i"
}
```

Now you can simply run `npm i` from the `A` folder which will first install the dependencies for the `B` folder (through the `preinstall`) before to install the ones for your folder `A`